# What is `copy to target` in Build Rules in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.6, targets

When I goto `TARGETS - Build Rules - All` in Xcode, I am seeing some files asking permission to copy to target.

[image]

What are those files?

Is it necessary to copy them to target?

What will happen after copying them to target?

I'm using xcode 4.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build rules define what to do with the various files that have been added to the given target. Xcode includes a number of "built-in" rules for processing things like source files, image resources, etc. That's what you're seeing here.

You can hit the "Copy to Target" button to copy the rule from Xcode's read-only defaults into your target-defined rules so that you can modify it.